# Jboss Accessing over internet with http 80 port

Tags: jboss, installation

I have amazon redhat server instance with jboss installed on it.By default jboss running port is 8080 and by disabling firewall its running on port `http://{myip}:8080`.But I want to change its default port to 80.For that i made changes in standalone.xml file of jboss on line:

```
From
<socket-binding name="http" port="8080">

To 
<socket-binding name="http" port="80">
```

and then restart jboss server still its not working on 80 port.Any suggestion.
Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't be `port="80"`? was it a typo?

Comment: I  have updated my question its port="80"

Comment: `$ sudo system-config-firewall-tui` and allow www traffic. Maybe it works

Comment: I had tried it but its not working.In question its already told that firewall is disabled

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read well.